# Prestashop 1.6 - edit site in code

Tags: php, prestashop

I am using PRESTASHOP 1.6 and i am  trying to edit some page content like class in header. I try edit or delete all TPL files in directory /themes/default-bootstrap and no one make changes on my web page?

How i can edit header or any other part of my page with code?

Comment: Hi, are you sure you are using default-bootstrap as your template ? You can check this in Preferences > Themes. And what are your cache options in Advanced parameters > Performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by ébewè in the comment section, first check that you are using the right theme in `Preferences > Themes` in your backoffice. Then check in `Advanced Parameters > Performance` that in `Smarty` section `Never recompile template files` isn't checked or use the `clear cache` option.

Comment: Thanks dude, i disable cacheing and clear all and work now thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me, all cacheing settings was off but i steal need to clear cache to show some changes?